# delete files matching pattern

Tags: bash, files, find, wildcards

I need to recursively remove all files in all subdirs where the filename contains a number followed by an 'x' followed by a number, at least two times.

Example:

I'd want to remove these files:

```
'aaa-12x123-123x12.jpg'
'aaa-12x12-123x12-12x123.jpg'
```

But I do NOT want to remove these files:

```
'aaa.jpg'
'aaa-12x12.jpg'
'aaaxaaa-123x123.jpg'
'aaaxaaa-aaaxaaa.jpg'
```

How can I do that (from the bash shell)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A string contains “a number followed by an `x` followed by a number” if and only if it contains a digit followed by an `x` followed by a digit, i.e. if it contains a substring matching the pattern `[0-9]x[0-9]`. So you're looking to remove the files whose name matches the pattern `*[0-9]x[0-9]*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg`.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*[0-9]x[0-9]*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg' -delete
```

If your `find` doesn't have `-delete`, call `rm` to delete the files.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*[0-9]x[0-9]*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Thank you! 12.000 files gone i 2 sec. That saved me some manual labour!

Comment: Neither `-delete` nor `-exec rm` worked for me in Bash on Windows. But this did: `find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*[0-9]x[0-9]*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg' | xargs rm`

Comment: @Tamlyn Use `-print0` and `xargs -0`, otherwise the command will fail with file names containing spaces or single quotes. But `-delete` and `-exec rm` *do* work on Windows. If something doesn't work, it's not due to their use.

Comment: Will this work with Windows as well?

Comment: It'll work if you have a port of Unix utilities such as Cygwin or GNUWin32. Obviously it won't work out of the box on Windows. Take care that Windows has an unrelated program called `find`, so make sure the Unix utilities are first in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The right command is:

`find . -type f -iregex '.*[0-9]x[0-9]*\.jpg$'`

this will grab only files with names: 'aaa-12x12.jpg', but not 'aaa-12x12red.jpg'